# Sorting Array List containing strings and integers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

If I have an `ArrayList` as the following:

`["a 100", "b 32", "t 54", "u 1"]` (numbers and letter are separated by space in each cell of the array list).

How can I sort it by numbers  keeping each number with its corresponding letter?.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A primary search by the string part and the secondary by the integer part?

Comment: Google `java comparator`. That is how you can sort a list by some custom property or definition of order.

Comment: is that pattern always the same?? can we assume all elements in the list are composed as "1Char+space+Anumber"

Comment: @Maljam I disagree that OP needs to show much effort here as they should not be expected to write a sorting algorithm to solve this problem, they presumably don't know about comparators, and it's not obvious what search would lead to the information that they need. (it turns out that `java sort by` seems to be good enough, but this is more a testament to Google's impressiveness than anything)

Comment: It looks like your list shouldn't be storing Strings but objects of your own class which could store String and int. This would give you a lot of flexibility when you would like to search/sort based on one of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use swapping method just like in regular arrays. The only difference is that we use `set(index, "value")` method to update a specific string at specified index.

```
public static void sort (ArrayList<String> arr){    

    int N = arr.size();
    int E = N-1;
    String temp;
    boolean flag = true;

    while(flag){
        flag=false;

        for(int a = 0 ; a < E ; a++){
            if(Integer.parseInt(arr.get(a).substring(arr.get(a).indexOf(" ")+1)) > 
               Integer.parseInt(arr.get(a+1).substring(arr.get(a+1).indexOf(" ")+1))) {

                temp=arr.get(a);
                arr.set(a, arr.get(a+1));   
                arr.set(a+1, temp);

                flag=true;
            }   
        }
        E--;    
    }}
```

The sorting algorithm is bubble sort. I have used it due to simplicity. You can use any other sorting algorithm if you want.

Then, you can call the `sort()` function in main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    arr.add("a 98");
    arr.add("a 23");
    arr.add("c 11");

    sort(arr);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is slow.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you are trying to implement object oriented programming using strings. Luckily, Java has already done this.

So, do something like this instead:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    private final String aString; //could be char perhaps..
    private final Integer anInteger;

    public MyClass(final String aString, final Integer anInteger) {
        this.aString = aString;
        this.anInteger = anInteger;
    }

    public String getAString() { return aString; }
    public Integer getAnInteger() { return anInteger; }

    public String toString() { return anInteger + " " + aString }

    //comparison by number
    public int compareTo(final MyClass other) {
        return anInteger.compareTo(other.anInteger);
    }
}
```

Then, you use it like this:

```
final List<MyClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<>();
myClasses.add(new MyClass("a", 100));
myClasses.add(new MyClass("b", 32));
myClasses.add(new MyClass("t", 54));
myClasses.add(new MyClass("u", 1));

Collections.sort(myClasses);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom comparator to sort the list.

```
List<String> yourList = Arrays.asList("a 100", "b 32", "t 54", "u 1");
yourList.sort((entry1, entry2) -> {
    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(entry1.split(" ")[1]);
    int number2 = Integer.parseInt(entry2.split(" ")[1]);

    return Integer.compare(number1, number2);
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
```

Just import static `Integer` methods and you'll get the most compact `Comparator<String>` for your purpose.

```
(a, b) -> compare(valueOf(a.split(" ")[1]), valueOf(b.split(" ")[1]));
```

Comment: import statements ending with `*` are poor practice.  Better to use `import static java.lang.Integer.valueOf;` instead.

Comment: @VGR, yes, I know that, but the love for the shortest answers will kill me :) By the way, here we should have 2 static imports for `compare` and `valueOf` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements in the list are the same pattern:

then you can do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  ["a 100", "b 32", "t 54", "u 1"]
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("a 100");
    myList.add("b 32");
    myList.add("t 54");
    myList.add("u 1");
    System.out.println("List unsorted" + myList);
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            try {
                int a1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(2));
                int a2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(2));
                return Integer.compare(a1,a2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("List sorted" + myList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html) has a handful of `static` and `default` methods that make it easy to create custom comparators. For instance, you could create one that splits each string and converts the second word to an integer.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(
    s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[1])
));
```